# Reading the value of 31st bit of a 32bit integer

Tags: c, gcc, arm

For reading the 31th bit(MSB) of a 32bit integer one method is as below

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int b =0x80005000;
    if(b&(1<<31))
        printf("bit is one\n");
    else
        printf("bit is zero\n");
return 0;
}
```

My question is, is there any other optimum method to do this with less instruction cycles?

Comment: Just predefine masks that you need.

Comment: @LongSmith - assuming that the compiler isn't too stupid, the mask is predefined

Comment: Have you compiled the code with maximum optimization and looked at the generated code?

Comment: @4386427 compiler optimizes very many of things, however it is not a reason for writing inefficient code and relying only on the "smartness" of your compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In two's complement representation, the MSB is set when the number is negative and clear when the number is non-negative, so this would also work.

```
int b = 0x80005000;
if (b < 0)
    printf("bit is one\n");
else
    printf("bit is zero\n");
```

In fact, for the `if(b&(1<<31))` code *you* wrote, GCC does produce assembly that compares to 0 and checks the sign - identical to the output that GCC generates on this code.